# Java 8 and Cucumber don't run the step files with lambdas methods

Tags: java-8, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, selenide

I have a great problem and I have tried to solve this problem, but all time is the same.
I have this scenario with cucumber

[feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPmMq.jpg)

And this is the steps' file

[steps' file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR0WL.jpg)

Finally I run with

```
package Steps;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"./src/test/java/features"},
        glue = {"./src/test/java/Steps"},
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:reports/cucumber-html-report","json:cucumber.json"}
)
public class Orquestador {

}
```

And the consolo of intellij appear this:

[ans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z8GA.jpg)

these are all my files
[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9jR3.jpg)

I am using Mac OS

Thanks :)

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cucumber is not finding your step definitions. Provide the correct "glue" to the location of your step definitions when running the feature file.